# Como abrir arquivos .zip encriptados?

Tags: golang, arquivo-zip

Estou tentando abrir arquivos .zip com senha, usando senhas existentes em outro arquivo .txt.

A função do código que faz a abertura do arquivo:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/yeka/zip"
)

//criando constante
const (
    zipPath  = "./assets/batlorem.zip"
    passPath = "./assets/rockyou2.txt"
)

func main() {
    abrirArquivoZip()
}

func abrirArquivoZip() {

    arquivos, err := zip.OpenReader(zipPath)

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Erro: %v, %v\n", err, arquivos))
    }

    defer arquivos.Close()

    arquivo := arquivos.File[0]

    if arquivo.IsEncrypted() {

        listaSenhas := obterListaDeSenhas(passPath)

        timeStart := time.Now()

        for i := 0; i < len(listaSenhas); i++ {

            arquivo.SetPassword(listaSenhas[i])

            _, err := arquivo.Open()

            if err == nil {

                fmt.Printf("\nSenha encontrada: %v\n", listaSenhas[i])
                fmt.Printf("localizada na linha: %v\n", i+1)
                break
            }
        }

        fmt.Printf("\nTempo: %v\n", time.Since(timeStart))
    }
}
```

A função que cria faz a leitura das senhas e retornam um vetor de strings com elas:

```
func obterListaDeSenhas(caminhoArquivo string) (senhas []string) {

    arquivo, err := os.Open(caminhoArquivo)

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Erro: %v\n", err))
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(arquivo)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        senhas = append(senhas, scanner.Text())
    }

    defer arquivo.Close()

    arquivoStatus, err := os.Stat(caminhoArquivo)

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Erro: %v\n", err))
    }

    fmt.Printf("Nome Arquivo: %v\n", arquivoStatus.Name())
    fmt.Printf("Tamanho Arquivo: %v\n", arquivoStatus.Size()/1024)
    fmt.Printf("Quantidade de senhas: %v\n", len(senhas))

    return
}
```

Meu arquivo.txt com as senhas tem inumeras senhas cada uma em uma linha, como no exemplo:

```
123456
12345
123456789
password
iloveyou
princess
```

E o arquivo.zip contem um texto qualquer, o texto não é relevante é testar se o arquivo abre com algumas das senhas no .txt.

**O que eu observei:**

O código não esta retornando erro ao tentar abrir o arquivo com as senhas incorretas.

Verifiquei que não esta sendo retornado erro para nenhuma das tentativas com senha incorreta. Qual o motivo disso ?

O Código acima está completo mas pode ser testado mais facilmente [aqui](https://replit.com/@systemagic91/brute-force#main.go).

Comment: A pergunta foi fechada por "não ser objetiva" gostaria que fosse esclarecido o que não esta objetivo na pergunta. Pois acho que o meu problema esta claro.

Comment: Tem certeza que a IF esta entrando em `if arquivo.IsEncrypted() {` ? Por favor, para conseguirmos ajudar basta [edit] crie um [mcve] que possamos testar de forma simples. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: Pelo que entendi ficou faltando verificar: `if err != nil` no momento que faz o  `arquivo.Open()` ... porque provavelmente é isso que está acontecendo, mas não verifiquei todo o seu código. Só debugando.

Comment: @Danizavtz Nesse caso eu estou esperando que o código retorne erro para todas as senhas que são diferentes da senha correta então no caso seria `if err == nil` mesmo pois o código deve informar com qual senha ele conseguiu abrir o arquivo.

Comment: Tem como reabrir a pergunta? Gostaria de postar uma solução.

Comment: @Danizavtz Você pode votar para reabrir a pergunta, faltam 3 votos para reabertura.

Comment: Não tenho reputação. :-/ @water

Comment: @water, [solução](https://replit.com/@danizavtz/maingo#main.go)

Comment: Eu acabei colocando a condição `if err != nil` naquele trecho do código para fazer a próxima iteração do laço. É o momento que eu chamo o `continue`. @water

Comment: Obrigado. Quando a pergunta for reaberta vc poderia postar sua explicação por favor? Não entendi o motivo de `arquivo.Open()` **não** estar retornando erro quando tenta abrir o arquivo com a senha errada. @Danizavtz

Comment: O que detecta a senha incorreta é o trecho que tem o `ioutil.ReadAll()` pois é ali que existe o erro ao fazer a leitura dos dados. Estava faltando este trecho em seu código. Eu peguei o código do repositório da lib  `"github.com/yeka/zip"`